# removing floats from bootstrap navbar without affecting layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i am basically new to css and trying to build a bootstrap navbar ,the issue is that i had to center certain contents of the navbar I.E , center the menu items .

basically after going through the source of the bootstrap navbar i figured out that the reason all elements in the navbar appear in one line rather then moving on to the next line is because the elements in the navbar are floated either right or left , the movement you remove the floats the alignment is broken ,

so what i tried to do is : - HTML code(TYPICAL bootstrap markup) :

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
             <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a> -->
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://images.dailyo.in/images/facebook_two.png" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the CSS(customized css) :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse  ul.navbar-nav{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    width: 300px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse  ul.navbar-nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.brand-holder {
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
}


.navbar-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The thing to notice is see how i have removed the floats in `ul.navbar-nav` and `ul.navbar-nav li`

Fiddle [here .](http://jsfiddle.net/q3zay6xa/1/) , now see how the contents of

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://images.dailyo.in/images/facebook_two.png" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
```

is floated to the next line . is there anyway that i can have the contents back inline with the menu items ?

**P.S.** :: i would really like to avoid using absolute positioning .

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your expected layout? I think it's better that you can draw it out

Comment: @RLam , Thanks for asking ram , its not some complex layout , its very simple , http://jsfiddle.net/q3zay6xa/2/ , see when how i remove my styles (CSS) , the left facebook logo appears inline . i want that FB icon to be inline !

Comment: can you please clarify - inline with what ?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding of your question is correct, probably by changing the CSS as below

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse  ul.navbar-nav{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    text-align:left;
```

and instead of keeping an another UL for the FB Logo keep the whole Li as in the first Ul itself and aligning to right, should help

so the final html will be

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
         <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a> -->       <!-- </div>-->
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="#"><img src="http://images.dailyo.in/images/facebook_two.png" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

You can have a check on the result [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3zay6xa/8/)

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Philemon

Comment: Thanks alot ...  But the main navbar elements have to be center aligned ! , ur fiddle has them left aligned !